# Good All-in-one excel template for SCRUM framework?

Tags: scrum

In our team we want to use SCRUM but for the moment we don't want to use a tool (most of them are not really free or just for limited number of project/users). Because agile is about simplicity, we think a good starting point to follow-up a SCRUM project would be to use an appropriate excel template. At the end *Agile is a pathway*.

Looking on internet, there are some specific excel file such as: product-backlog, sprint backlog, burndown chart, etc. I am wondering about some excel with all in one together and selft-contained and simple to use.

The most complete one I have found are:

- [this one Petri Heiramo, CollabNet](http://www.odd-e.com/resources/template_backlogs/ph_product_sprint_backlog_0.03.xls) but I guess no one maintains it (probably it was the early stage of CollabNet).
- There is another one from [MKB Software Expert](http://www.mkbsoftwareexpert.nl/download-scrum-tools/) that is a good one too.

I am looking for something that includes and integrate (I know it sounds like an application, but excel is very powerful tool):

- Product vision
- Release Plan
- Product Backlog Burndown
- Spring Backlog
- Resource Allocation
- Impediment List

Here some additional resources I have found on the internet about this topic:

It is an example, for parking lot application, with an executive dashboard (manual update) and with Product Backlog and Sprint Backlog
https://www.scrumalliance.org/resources/8

Add-in: (I don't know how it works for Excel 2013)
https://www.scrumalliance.org/resources/48

Seem to be provided by Petri Heiramo from Collabnet (this is the best I have found)
https://www.odd-e.com/resources/template_backlogs/ph_product_sprint_backlog_0.03.xls

It contents Production Vision and Impediment list
http://www.mkbsoftwareexpert.nl/download-scrum-tools/

Reference to some good templates some from Bas Vodde collection and Petri Heiramo
http://agilesoftwaredevelopment.com/tags-860/scrum/scrum-backlog-templates-and-examples/

Other references
https://www.odd-e.com/home_page/html_files/bl_templates.html

Good Product Backlog with macros for updating the information (click on the link: A backlog from a company starting with a "c")
https://www.odd-e.com/home_page/html_files/bl_example.html

Just provide a screen shot, but gives you some idea about how to document user story
https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/a-sample-format-for-a-spreadsheet-based-product-backlog

Simple, it generates cards
https://www.equinox.co.nz/blog/agile-excel-story-templates-for-backlogs-and-release-planning

**What would be in your opinion a good excel all-in-one for managing and monitoring SCRUM projects?**

**Note**: I am aware it can be considered as typical *shopping/software question*, the border can be diffuse because Project Management is about: Procedures, Techniques, Tools and its best practices applied to project management, therefore sometimes is impossible to talk about it without mentioning some specific technique and tools.

Comment: You should still avoid asking for a specific tool, because then your question tends to become obsolete quickly, which makes it useless for others. Instead, try to structure your question in such as way that any answers will be timeless; focus on your problem itself, rather than just 'what currently-available tool is best to solve this?'

Comment: @Sarov: I understand your concern, but I think the interpretation about "software type question" is too rigid for this particular forum (Project Management). My question is similar to this one: "Please help me on which bus to take for going from A to B" I know for sure after a certain time the schedule is going to change and even the buses,  but people need this kind of help, that is why people use Google Map. Re-phrasing the question like this: "Please advise for "any anyway" of going from A to B" is more generic but it is not helpful (you need a specific tool). IMHO

Comment: This is a "shopping" question, and is off-topic everywhere but Software Recommendations Stack Exchange. Questions about how to use a tool to support a process are often on-topic, but questions about what tool (or template, plugin, or macro) to use are inherently shopping questions that are both too specific to your individual use case and too opinion-based to fit our Q&A format.

Comment: @CodeGnome, I am not asking for tools, my question is specific to Excel and how to have a spreadsheet to support follow-up of Scrum project. For me its a question of how to use excel for a given purpose and collect all the information about best Excel alternatives. Why in Quora you can put a [question](https://www.quora.com/Has-anybody-successfully-managed-Scrum-with-Excel-as-the-key-tool) similar to this one, but not here? Stack Exchange is not satisfying an existing need. In MHO this rule can not be applied in the same way for all forums. PM is about process, techniques, and tools

Comment: @DavidLeal Comments are not for extended discussion. If you have a question or concern about the community standards or what the Stack Exchange and PMSE communities have defined as on-topic, please go ahead and raise the issues on [meta](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @CodeGnome thank you for the tip, I already posted a question to PM meta see [here](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/811/shall-this-site-have-an-specific-definition-of-shopping-question). I hope this debate would help to understand better what does a "shopping question" mean  in the context of this site.

Comment: This is my personal answer to this question, I put it as a comment because the question is closed. [Here](https://cibertambor.blogspot.com/2017/08/mastering-scrum-project-with-excel.html) is a detail explanation about the template I am using. It is the Petri Heiramo template (I mentioned in my question) with some corrections and extension added by me. In case it helps.

Comment: "...is too rigid for this particular forum..." 

"Comments are not for extended discussion." ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

This may be one of those frustrating, "easier to build it yourself" questions. Excel doesn't necessarily provide great affordances for tracking a backlog, sprint, etc., but it is easy to envision lots of ways it could be used in that way, with rows for individual stories, columns for things like storypoints, etc. You can even invent ways to track (or at least display) tasks--reserve your first few columns for epic / story / task, say, and fill in the relevant columns (story points for story, for instance) as needed; tag various rows as needed, copy stories to an active sprint workbook, etc.

The reason you may want to feel you way into building it yourself is that you are looking for those affordances that make it easy to fit what =you= want to track and how your team best understands things, without having to fit someone else's "round peg into a square hole" take on the problem.

Modeling in Excel yourself may make it easier for you to know if, and to which to migrate your tracking at some point in the future.

Comment: thanks, I am not an Excel expert, and for this particular case, we need some macros (too keep uptodate all the information), I feel more comfortable adapting to my need an existing one. Actually, this what I am doing. I am wondering if there is any popular well know best in class excel file, so I can take this and adapt it to my need or if someone from the community is willing to share some good template.